# passing pandas data frame column to a classifier function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parameter-passing, classification

I need to run ZeroShotClassificationPipeline on a column of my data frame named 'TEXT'.When I try to pass the column as my input I dace below error. I tried different alternatives like .apply or .pipe() bot it did not some my problem.

```
from transformers import pipeline
import pandas as pd
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli", device=0)
classifier(df['TEXT'], candidate_labels=label, multi_class=True)
```

the error is:

````
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```
````

Comment: try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73485185/apply-zero-shot-transformer-model-to-each-row-and-create-new-columns-in-pandas